# Unity how to validate/preprocess variables when they're assigned in the inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a string[] animationPaths variable. And I am using the OdinInspector library to drag and drop files into the inspector to get their paths.

I want to preprocess the paths in order to remove the final ".prefab" extensions.

```
[OnValueChanged("UpdateAnimationPaths")]
[FilePath(ParentFolder = "Assets/Project/Resources")]
[SerializeField] private string[] animationPaths;
```

The OnValueChanged callback allows me to process the variables when one is changed. But the callback is not called when a variable is first assigned in the inspector.

Is there any way to preprocess variables the moment they are assigned in the inspector? (Without using the Update function)

Comment: To the person who downvoted this question - atleast mention the reason why it was downvoted and provide the oppurtunity to the questioner to modify it. Simply downvoting without comments is not going to help a new comer. You need to understand that it was easier for people who joined earlier to get up votes for their questions and answers. Now it is very difficult because many who joined earlier had already asked basic questions or answered those basic questions and they are still earning votes from those. For a new comer it is really difficult to get votes. Have some consideration for that.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html)? This method is always called if anything is changed via the Inspector (and only then)

Comment: Thanks derHugo. I believe that's what I'm looking for. But wouldn't that be called for every variable that changes? Isn't there any callback for single variables? (Like the OnValueChanged one?)

Comment: Following @derHugo aproximation, you can use OnValidate as he said, and check if (variableToCheck != variableToCheckPreviousValue), you need to store the "previous value", ofc

Comment: @DawitAbraham in short: No. You could of course build your own custom [`Editor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html)/[`PropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) script and do the check there only if that specific field is changed. But yeah other then that how Lotan mentioned you could always store the last value and then compare it in `OnValidate`.

Comment: Thanks @derHugo and Lotan. I appreciate the help!